# Leaves of the maple tree turn from green to red

Tags: difference

What is the difference between 'leaves of the maple tree turn from green to red' and 'leaves of the maple tree turn green to red'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turn), **turn** can mean

> **turn verb (BECOME)**
>
> B2 [ L, I or T usually + adv/prep]
> to (cause to) become, change into, or come to be something:

Note the L, I or T in the definition: this means that **turn** can be a [Linking verb](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/linking_verbs.htm), Intransitive or Transitive.

> leaves of the maple tree turn from green to red

This sentence is an Intransitive usage: the verb has no object. It means that the leaves start off green, and become red.

> leaves of the maple tree turn green to red

This sentence is a linking verb usage: the adjective **green** follows the verb, so it means that the leaves become green. It is not at all clear what **to red** relates to.